# How to get data from Firebase Database in a loop?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

in my code I have a list of products barcode and in my Firebase Database I have values inside this barcodes, like this: [image: BarCode structure].

I'm trying to retrieve the barcodes datas in a loop, but I cannot handle with this. Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listaBarCodeProdutos.size() ; i ++ ){
            String barCode = (String) listaBarCodeProdutos.get(i);
            Query query = produtosRef.orderByKey().equalTo(barCode);
            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        //Limpa o hash map
                        listaMercadosCB.clear();
                        //Salva os mercados e os preços e um hashmap
                        listaMercadosCB = (HashMap) snapshot.child("mercados").getValue();
                        //This is to parse the HashMap keys to Array                         
                        Object[] listaIdsCB = listaMercadosCB.keySet().toArray();


                        //add esse obj em um array de objetos
                        listaCB.add(listaIdsCB);
                        Log.i("listaCB1", String.valueOf(listaCB));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```

This code saves all data in barcode child in a `HashMap`, but when I try to get this `HashMap` value using `Log.i("listaMercadosCB", String.valueOf(listaMercadosCB));`  after the loop, it returns null...

This is the logcat for the values: `02-13 19:44:17.146 13903-13903/com.example.mts_rodrigues.projetocartolada I/listaMercadosCB: {wrxYaHZuLBTfrPrrvThxQREFzK02=4.5, d63vvncs2gh6PSnxFAjxhTOayyq1=2.9}`

> This is inside the loop

`02-13 19:44:17.066 13903-13903/com.example.mts_rodrigues.projetocartolada I/listaMercadosCB: {}`

> This is after de loop

I guess that the value outside the loop is called before the Firebase Database retrieved him inside the loop...

All this codes are inside the `onCreate()` method.
 Anyone can help me ? Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like things are working as expected: the data isn't available until `onDataChange` has executed, so you can't use it before that. Most likely you'll need to move the code that needs the data **into** `onDataChange()`. Also see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener

Comment: Thanks :D it's very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct way in which you can use the data that you get from a Firebase Realtime database. You are guessing right. `onDataChange()` method has an asynchronous behaviour, which means that your data si not available until this method is executed. A quick solution would be to use that data only inside `onDataChange()` method, or if you want to use it outside, dive in the asynchronous world and use the last part of my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774).